# Как реализовать фильтрацию геометок в Яндекс карте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, яндекс-карты

Впервые столкнулся с такой задачей, да и в принципе вся работа с Яндекс картами до этого заканчивалась просто добавлением карты на сайт. Как можно реализовать фильтрацию геометок в Яндекс карте по соответствующим табам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В геометках использую svg изображения. Может, это можно сделать по цвету или по другим каким-то свойствам? В данной теме я полный ноль, так что любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: А кроме изображений меткам никаких других свойств/параметров не добавляли что-ли кроме координат? В чём сложность влепить им кастомные параметры, по которым и фильтровать? Ну и пример фильтрации у Яндекса тоже есть, чем не подходит? https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobjects_menu